# order of vector cross-product for a CCW triangle

Tags: opengl, normals

I need to calculate normal vector for a triangle prepared for passing to opengl chain. It has vertexes enumerated in counter-clockwise order that is default for opengl. Let denote them as `A`, `B`, `C`, and put `C-B` as `u` and `B-A` as `v`.

In what order should I cross product vectors to gain normal vector codirectional with the normal calculated by internal opengl procedures? `v × u` or `u × v`?

I've found many topics about face-culling and vertex ordering, but not about computation normals for triangle that depends from vertex order as well as from the coordinate system orientation.

Comment: if you only care about collinearity then it doesn't matter because `v x u = -(u x v)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Right hand rule, assuming your triangle is A,B,C in CCW order. then you need

```
Normal = Cross(B-A, C-A);
```

The way you set u,v and is inconsistent both vectors should have the same tail it's more consistent this way.

If you want to use u,v the way you set, it is `v x u` using [right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: for what reason should vectors have the same tail? `C-A = -(A-C)` and cycling through A,B,C we can express normal in terms of `u` and `v`

Comment: it's more consistent this way, you can just use the right hand rule though.

Comment: @ayvango if there is anything not clear I can provide more info. please feel free to ask.

Comment: All things are clear. The coordinate system is right-oriented and this  complete understanding